# Make icons pop out only on icon hover not div

Tags: css

Hi i am attemptting to make a pop out menu, so when the main icon is hovered or clicked if need be, then the other icons slide out left and right. But currently it pops out when you hover anywhere in the div container rather then just the main icon (icon 3 in this case).

I dont mind having to use script but even then have not been able to islote it.

here is the code:

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oxe6jg1L/2/

html:

```
<div class="social-icons">
            <div class="social-icons-image">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="test">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="social-icons-image">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="test">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="social-icons-image">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="Test">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="social-icons-image">
                <a href="https://plus.google.com">
                    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="test">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="social-icons-image">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="Linkedin Icon">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.social-icons {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 640px;
    height: 128px;
    position: relative;
}


.social-icons .social-icons-image {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 33%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .5s;
    padding: 2%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.social-icons .social-icons-image a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


.social-icons img {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.social-icons a:hover img {
    width: 110%;
    height: auto;
    margin: -5%;
}

.social-icons .social-icons-image:nth-child(1) {
    left: 33.755%;   /*(nth-child(2).left - (50% * 20%)/4)*/
    top: 25%; /*((100%-50%)/2)*/
    z-index: 0;
    width: 10%; /*(50% * 20%)*/
    height: auto;
    opacity: .5;
}


.social-icons .social-icons-image:nth-child(2) {
    left: 36.25%;   /*(40% - (75% * 20%)/4)*/
    top: 12.5%; /*((100%-75%)/2)*/
    z-index: 1;
    width: 15%; /*(75% * 20%)*/
    height: auto;
    opacity: .75;
}

.social-icons .social-icons-image:nth-child(3) {
    left: 40%;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
}

.social-icons .social-icons-image:nth-child(4) {
    left: 48.75%; /*(60% - 3*(75% * 20%)/4*/
    top: 12.5%; /*((100%-75%)/2)*/
    z-index: 1;
    width: 15%; /*(75% * 20%)*/
    height: auto;
    opacity: .75;
}

.social-icons .social-icons-image:nth-child(5) {
    left: 56.25%;   /*(nth-child(4).left + (nth-child(4).width- 3*(50% * 20%)/4)*/
    top: 25%; /*((100%-50%)/2)*/
    z-index: 0;
    width: 10%; /*(50% * 20%)*/
    height: auto;
    opacity: .5;
}

.social-icons:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0%;
    width: 20%;
    opacity: 1;
}

.social-icons:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(2) {
    top: 0px;
    left: 20%;
    width: 20%;
    opacity: 1;
}

.social-icons:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(4) {
    top: 0px;
    left: 60%;
    width: 20%;
    opacity: 1;
}

.social-icons:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(5) {
    top: 0px;
    left: 80%;
    width: 20%;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: with no javascript and therefore no jquery, why did you tag this question with those two tags?

Comment: the answer is, because `.social-icons:hover`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You added hover property on `social-icons` class that's why it's working on `div`. I added one more inner `div` into `social-icons` div and added all property on that `div`. New div class is `social-icons-inner`

```css
.social-icons {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 640px;
    height: 128px;
    position: relative;
}


.social-icons .social-icons-image {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 33%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .5s;
    padding: 2%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.social-icons .social-icons-image a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


.social-icons img {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.social-icons a:hover img {
    width: 110%;
    height: auto;
    margin: -5%;
}

.social-icons .social-icons-image:nth-child(1) {
    left: 33.755%;   /*(nth-child(2).left - (50% * 20%)/4)*/
    top: 25%; /*((100%-50%)/2)*/
    z-index: 0;
    width: 10%; /*(50% * 20%)*/
    height: auto;
    opacity: .5;
}


.social-icons .social-icons-image:nth-child(2) {
    left: 36.25%;   /*(40% - (75% * 20%)/4)*/
    top: 12.5%; /*((100%-75%)/2)*/
    z-index: 1;
    width: 15%; /*(75% * 20%)*/
    height: auto;
    opacity: .75;
}

.social-icons .social-icons-image:nth-child(3) {
    left: 40%;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 20%;
    height: auto;
}

.social-icons .social-icons-image:nth-child(4) {
    left: 48.75%; /*(60% - 3*(75% * 20%)/4*/
    top: 12.5%; /*((100%-75%)/2)*/
    z-index: 1;
    width: 15%; /*(75% * 20%)*/
    height: auto;
    opacity: .75;
}

.social-icons .social-icons-image:nth-child(5) {
    left: 56.25%;   /*(nth-child(4).left + (nth-child(4).width- 3*(50% * 20%)/4)*/
    top: 25%; /*((100%-50%)/2)*/
    z-index: 0;
    width: 10%; /*(50% * 20%)*/
    height: auto;
    opacity: .5;
}

.social-icons-inner:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0%;
    width: 20%;
    opacity: 1;
}

.social-icons-inner:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(2) {
    top: 0px;
    left: 20%;
    width: 20%;
    opacity: 1;
}

.social-icons-inner:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(4) {
    top: 0px;
    left: 60%;
    width: 20%;
    opacity: 1;
}

.social-icons-inner:hover .social-icons-image:nth-child(5) {
    top: 0px;
    left: 80%;
    width: 20%;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-icons">
  <div class="social-icons-inner">
            <div class="social-icons-image">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="test">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="social-icons-image">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="test">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="social-icons-image">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="Test">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="social-icons-image">
                <a href="https://plus.google.com">
                    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="test">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="social-icons-image">
                <a href="">
                    <img src="https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png" alt="Linkedin Icon">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
```